# Local phantomjs/highcharts export server on tomcat,export to png timeout

Tags: java, tomcat, svg, highcharts

I have successfully installed phantomjs and highcharts on a Windows system per instructions Setting Up Export Server, I can preview pictures in type png,jpeg, pdf and svg+xml, can download pictures in PDF or svg+xml type, but when I try to download in type png or jpeg, the log in tomcat console print as:

> [DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 10:24:21] (AbstractPool.java:poolCleaner:73)
> in cleanpool, the surplus or shortage is: 0 [DEBUG] [Timer-5146
> 10:24:22] (TimeOut.java:run:18) Timed out while downloading.
>
> [ERROR]
> [http-nio-8080-exec-1 10:24:22] (SVGConverter.java:requestServer:142)
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out [DEBUG]
> [http-nio-8080-exec-1 10:24:22] (ServerObjectFactory.java:validate:59)
> server didn't pass validation

the chrome browser returned

> Timeout converting SVG, is your file this big, or maybe you have a syntax error in the javascript callback?

I will be thankful for any help you can provide.

Comment: phantomjs version:2.0.0
tomcat version:8.5
jkd version:1.7.0_07

Comment: Take a look at this topic forum: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/set-up-of-export-server-t30774/. Also, did you consider to use the newer version of export server (Node Export Server). More detail can be found here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server.